# I am looking for a way for a trigger to insert into a second table only where the value in table 1 changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am looking for a way for a trigger to insert into a second table only where the value in table 1 changes. It is essentially an audit tool to trap any changes made. The field in table 1 is price and we want to write additional fields.

This is what I have so far.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER zmerps_Item_costprice__update_history_tr ON [ITEM] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
insert into zmerps_Item_costprice_history
        select  NEWID(), -- unique id
                GETDATE(),  -- CURRENT_date
                'PRICE_CHANGE', -- reason code
                a.ima_itemid, -- item id
                a.ima_price-- item price

            FROM  Inserted b inner join item a
                    on b.ima_recordid = a.IMA_RecordID
```

The table only contains a unique identifier, date, reference(item) and the field changed (price). It writes any change not just a price change

Comment: Can you edit your question and format the trigger code so we can read it? As it sits it is extremely difficult to decipher what is supposed to be there because the formatting is lost and there are comments all through it.

Comment: When an update query is executed the changed row is in both `inserted` and `deleted` (with respectively new and old values). You can join these on the primary key to get the updated rows and then you can just check if only the price changed. It can be a bit faster than joining the whole tables.

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as this? I moved some of the code around because comments after the comma between columns is just painful to maintain. You also should ALWAYS specify the columns in an insert statement. If your table changes this code will still work.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER zmerps_Item_costprice__update_history_tr ON [ITEM] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
insert into zmerps_Item_costprice_history
(
    UniqueID
    , CURRENT_date
    , ReasonCode
    , ItemID
    , ItemPrice
)
    select  NEWID()
        , GETDATE()
        , 'PRICE_CHANGE'
        , d.ima_itemid
        , d.ima_price
    FROM Inserted i 
    inner join deleted d on d.ima_recordid = i.IMA_RecordID
        AND d.ima_price <> i.ima_price
```

Comment: This only handle if there is a price change, OP wants to capture any change in any column...... `The field in table 1 is price and we want to write additional fields`

Comment: if the ima_price column allows null, it should be AND (d.ima_price <> i.ima_price OR d.ima_price IS NULL AND i.ima_price IS NOT NULL OR  d.ima_price IS NOT NULL AND i.ima_price IS NULL)

Comment: I interpreted it as a change in price which the above code will handle. If that isn't the case then it should be pretty simple for the OP to tweak it slightly.

Comment: I would also make the assumption that any table that is designed to store a price would not allow NULL for price. But again, without more details we don't know.

Comment: Go on tweak it slightly to handle the changes in other columns :) lets see how its done :)

Comment: Wow no need to get snarky. How could we tweak this to meet requirements that are not clear for tables we have no knowledge of?

Comment: ops wasn't trying to be snarky at all, just wanted to see if there was a simple way of doing it, since I am not aware of any fairly simple way of handling it :)

Comment: And maybe you weren't...stupid internet and not being able to hear inflection. Maybe the OP will come back and let us all know what they really want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any other column names I Have used Column2 and Column3 and the "Other" column names in the below example.

You can expand adding more columns in the below code.

overview about the query below:

Joined the deleted and inserted table (only targeting the rows that has changed) joining with the table itself will result in unnessacary processing of the rows which hasnt changed at all.

I have used NULLIF function to yeild a null value if the value of the column hasnt changed.

converted all the columns to same data type (required for unpivot) .

used unpivot to eliminate all the nulls from the result set.

unpivot will also give you the column name its has unpivoted it.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER zmerps_Item_costprice__update_history_tr 
ON [ITEM] 
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON ;

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  CAST(NULLIF(i.Price   , d.Price)    AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Price
       ,CAST(NULLIF(i.Column2 , d.Column2)  AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Column2
       ,CAST(NULLIF(i.Column3 , d.Column3)  AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Column3
FROM dbo.inserted i 
INNER JOIN dbo.deleted d ON i.IMA_RecordID = d.IMA_RecordID
WHERE i.Price   <> d.Price
 OR   i.Column2 <> d.Column2
 OR   i.Column3 <> d.Column3
 )
 INSERT INTO zmerps_Item_costprice_history
               (unique_id, [CURRENT_date], [reason code], Item_Value)
 SELECT  NEWID()
        ,GETDATE()
        ,Value
        ,ColumnName + '_Change'
 FROM CTE UNPIVOT (Value FOR ColumnName IN (Price , Column2, Column3) )up

END
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question correctly, You want to record change If and only if The column Price value is changes, you dont need any other column changes to be recorded

here is your code

```
CREATE  TRIGGER zmerps_Item_costprice__update_history_tr ON [ITEM] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
if update(ima_price)
insert into zmerps_Item_costprice_history
    select  NEWID(), -- unique id
            GETDATE(),  -- CURRENT_date
            'PRICE_CHANGE', -- reason code
            a.ima_itemid, -- item id
            a.ima_price-- item price

        FROM  Inserted b inner join item a
                on b.ima_recordid = a.IMA_RecordID
```